# How to get data output in CSV format?

Tags: javascript, csv

Here is my code:

```
var idFiltered = "";
var artists = [];
var country = "";
var released = "";
var genres = [];
var styles = [];
var tracklist = [];

var rows = [
  [idFiltered, artists, country, released, genres, styles, tracklist],
];

var csvContent = [];

function id(file) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      parsedLines = e.target.result.split(/\r|\n|\r\n/);
      resolve(parsedLines);
    };
    reader.readAsText(file);
  });
}

document.getElementById('fileInput').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  var file = e.target.files[0];

  if (file != undefined) {
    id(file).then(id => {
      console.log(id)
      console.log(parsedLines)
      console.log(typeof id);

      var idInt = id.map(Number);
      idFiltered = id.filter(function(v){return v!==''});

      console.log(idFiltered)

      idFiltered.forEach(idFiltered => {
        getRelease(idFiltered);
      });
      download(csvContent);
    });
  }
});

function getRelease(idFiltered) {
  return fetch(`https://api.*******.com/releases/${idFiltered}`, {
    'User-Agent': 'Dispodger/0.1',
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    if (data.message === 'Release not found.') {
      return { error: `Release with ID ${idFiltered} does not exist` };
    } else {
      const id = data.id;
      artists = data.artists ? data.artists.map(artist => artist.name) : [];
      country = data.country || 'Unknown';
      released = data.released_formatted || 'Unknown';
      genres = data.genres || [];
      styles = data.styles || [];
      tracklist = data.tracklist ? data.tracklist.map(track => track.title) : [];

      console.log(idFiltered);
      console.log(artists, country, released, genres, styles, tracklist)

      rows = [
        [idFiltered, artists, country, released, genres, styles, tracklist],
      ];

      console.log(rows);

    }
  });
}

function download() {
  const ROW_NAMES = ["Release ID", "artists", "country", "released", "genres", "styles", "tracklist"];
  csvContent = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,"
  + ROW_NAMES + "\n" + rows.map(e => e.join(",")).join("\n");

  console.log(csvContent);

  var encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent);
  var link = document.createElement("a");
  link.setAttribute("href", encodedUri);
  link.setAttribute("download", "my_data.csv");
  document.body.appendChild(link); // Required for FF
  link.click();
}
```

When I console.log `rows` on line 72, the data is clearly there, and it seems like I'm grabbing the data successfully but just throwing it away; it obviously never makes it into the `download` function. I originally had the download function as part of `GetRelease()`, but that wasn't working well, and I was getting one file per line, although with the data I wanted. Now I just get one file, but the data is absent, only the headers are included. Any help please? TIA.

Edit: I am starting to wonder if I'm perhaps returning the wrong thing from `getRelease`? Maybe instead of `return fetch` I need to do `return rows`?

Comment: `getRelease` is async. It returns a Promise, not a value. You can't simply do `idFiltered.forEach( getRelease )`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37576787/5008997 that will solve your problem :)

Comment: Thanks for the comments so far. @d0n.key - I think I get the general idea, but I'm not really sure what to do with that. Would that replace my entire `id` function, or just the `forEach` loop? I'm guessing the latter, but I can't write a function within another, can I?

Answer (score 1):

`getRelease` is async. It returns a Promise, not a value. You can't simply do `idFiltered.forEach( getRelease )`.

Solution : rewrite `getRelease` with the `async/await` syntax

```
async function getRelease(idFiltered) { // Returns a Promise

    const response = await fetch(...);

    const data = await response.json();

    if (data.message === 'Release not found.') {
        return { error: `Release with ID ${idFiltered} does not exist` };
    } else {
        // ....
        console.log(rows);
        return rows;
    }
}
```

Now you can do this :

```
for( let id of idFiltered){
    await getRelease(id);
}
```

This will make every `fetch` call in order, one after the other.
Alternatively, you can make them all in parallel with `Promise.all` :

```
await Promise.all( idFiltered.map(getRelease) );
```

Then you can `download(csvContent);`.

```
document.getElementById('fileInput')
    .addEventListener('change', async function (e) { // add "async"

        const file = e.target.files[0];

        if (!file) return;

        const id2 = await id(file);
        
        console.log(id2)
        console.log(parsedLines)
        console.log(typeof id2);

        const idFiltered = id2.filter(v => v !== '');

        console.log(idFiltered)

        await Promise.all(idFiltered.map(id => getRelease(id) ));

        download(csvContent);

    });
```

Comment: thanks, I'm trying that, but I'm getting "await is only valid in async functions, async generators and modules" for line 44. I tried making the `id` function async but that didn't seem to fix it. This is helpful to learn about, in any case.

Comment: Yes you need to add `async` to the functions that use `await`. `async` functions always return a Promise, not a value. I have updated my answer, rewrote your click handler. I noticed that you use the name `id` for several things. Don't do that, it gets confusing really quickly. I have used `id2`, rename it as you want.

Comment: Also I'm not sure why you filter an array of numbers by `v !== ''`?

Comment: I tried that, but the release IDs are all 0, so it's not working and not retrieving any data at all now. I'm not really sure about the filter either TBH.

Comment: What are `the release IDs`? Which variable, which line?

Comment: Well the variable in question will be `id`, but I don't know which line the error is occurring on, because there is no error message. It's just showing `https://api.*****.com/releases/0` where it should be showing `https://api.*****.com/releases/1' and so on.

Comment: But what's the output of `console.log(id2)`? (By the way I would really use more explicit variable names, like instead of `id` I'd use `fileToLines` or something and then `const lines = fileToLines(file)`. So one can understand what the code does and what it produces)

Comment: The output of `console.log(id2)` is 'Array(11) [ "1", "", "2", "", "3", "", "4", "", "5", "", … ]
​
0: "1"
​
1: ""
​
2: "2"
​
3: ""
​
4: "3"
​
5: ""
​
6: "4"
​
7: ""
​
8: "5"
​
9: ""
​
10: ""
​
length: 11
​
<prototype>: Array []
csv.js:60:17' I will definitely use better variable names once I work out better what everything does. My code is kind of cobbled together from various suggestions and I'm struggling to properly get a grip of it TBH.

Comment: I tried to remove the `idFiltered = id.filter(function(v){return v!==''});` and just use `id` as the variable throughout, but that just broke my program and I got a whole bunch errors, so reverted that change. There must be some reason why it's needed but IDK what it is.

Comment: OK now the filter makes sense, but it must be put before the conversion to numbers. Answer updated. Also, I have tried something different with `Promise.all`

Comment: Also `map(Number)` is useless; You can perfectly pass `"3"` instead of `3`, it will be appended to a URL anyway

Comment: Thanks, but that's still losing all the data that I had in the console before. When I console log rows I just get a bunch of empty arrays.

Comment: That's very strange. Could you please make a reproductible example online, for instance on [codepen](https://codepen.io/) ? Because really, I don't know what's wrong, but I don't have the full picture to troubleshoot it

Comment: How about this? https://codepen.io/double-happiness/pen/MWvrErX Thanks.

Comment: Aaaaah stupid me, I forgot to `await response.json`, silly mistake. I have forked and updated your Codepen : https://codepen.io/jeremythille/pen/OJjzQdg

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that out soon.

Comment: I just tried that out, and although it doesn't return data for all of the release IDs in the upload file, it did return one, so that's a real step forward! Thanks! :)

Comment: I tried the codepen with a CSV file I've made, with one number per row, and I got all the IDs. I don't know what yours looks like

Comment: That's odd, because I tried it again, and only got one line of output back. Could be a browser issue maybe? I'm on FF 94.0.1. I did manage to come up with a working version of my app. though; I could let you see it if you like.

Comment: Sure, you can update your Codepen, I'll gladly have a look

Comment: Done. (I'm currently working on the `delimiter` aspect, so that is not working properly yet). cheers